TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Default') on vue-leaflet
I have a vue project and i need to integrate map into it.I am using @vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet and i am getting this error.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Default')
Installed Dependencies
npm install leaflet @vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet

Created the map component
<template>
  <div style="height: 600px; width: 800px;">
    <l-map 
      ref="map" 
      v-model:zoom="zoom" 
      :center="center" 
      @click="onMapClick"
      style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
      <l-tile-layer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        layer-type="base"
        name="OpenStreetMap"
      ></l-tile-layer>
      <l-marker v-if="markerPosition" :lat-lng="markerPosition"></l-marker>
    </l-map>
    <div v-if="clickedLatLng">
      <p>Clicked Latitude: {{ clickedLatLng.lat }}</p>
      <p>Clicked Longitude: {{ clickedLatLng.lng }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker } from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "MapComponent",
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LMarker,
  },
  setup() {
    const zoom = ref(2);
    const center = ref([47.41322, -1.219482]);
    const markerPosition = ref(null);
    const clickedLatLng = ref(null);

    const onMapClick = (e) => {
      clickedLatLng.value = e.latlng;
      markerPosition.value = e.latlng;
    };

    return {
      zoom,
      center,
      markerPosition,
      clickedLatLng,
      onMapClick,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#map {
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>


https://github.com/vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet/issues/371
